# Gnuplot: performance plotting data via a pipe

Tags: gnuplot, pipe

I am trying to send some pseudo real-time data (1 kHz sample rate) via a pipe to gnuplot v4.6.3. The graphs are excellent if I slow the data down but unfortunately, gnuplot can't keep up so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for improving the performance.

I have noticed that the rate at which gnuplot can plot is heavily dependent on the size of the text window so I am guessing that one of the limiting factors is that gnuplot echos all of the piped commands to the text window. Does anyone know how to turn this off as it might solve my problem ?

I have tried the redirect solution mentioned here ([hide C++ Gnuplot pipe console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234530/hide-c-gnuplot-pipe-console-output)) but it doesn't seem to work under Windows.

Thanks very much,
John

Comment: Do you really need to plot at a kHz rate?  If you are plotting so that a human can keep an eye on the data, more than 10-20 frames per second seems a little excessive.  If you need to create plots to view later and the data are really coming in that fast, it seems like it would be reasonable to write the data to one big file and plot later.  Could you describe your situation a little more specifically?

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your thoughts.
1 kHz is the data slowed down from line speed and is really not that fast. E.g. for a 1024 point frame it is only a 1 second frame rate. FYI, Many other packages can easily support updates at this rate. Cheers John

Comment: I was using pgnuplot.exe as I didn't realize gnuplot.exe supported pipes. Using "gnuplot -persist > /nul 2>&1" has got the performance very high indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was using pgnuplot.exe as I didn't realize gnuplot.exe supported pipes. Using "gnuplot -persist > /nul 2>&1" has got the performance - very high indeed :-)